# Using a var as agrument 2 in addChild method for writing XML

Tags: php, xml

Here i parse some data from a webpage.

I want to write it to an file. It all works ok when i use some test strings in

```
$xml->addChild('alink', 'test');
```

But when i try and write in the data i actually need to use

```
$xml->addChild('alink', $value);
```

It doesnt work.

Message is :

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addChild() [simplexmlelement.addchild]: unterminated entity reference .wvx= in C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\My Documents\Downloads\XAMPP_1.7.1\xampp\htdocs\PhpTest2\index.php on line 96
```

Complete code. Why does addChild not let me use a var there as agrument 2 in that method? And what is the word around to getting that working. Can find no explanation on php.net

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument(); 
@$dom->loadHtml($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $articleList = $xpath->query("//body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a");

    $xml = new SimpleXmlElement('<links></links>');
    $xml->addChild('dvd');

    foreach ($articleList as $art)
    {
        $value = $art->getAttribute('href');
        $xml->addChild('alink', $value);
    }

    $xml->asXML('/simplexml_create.xml');
```

Many Thanks,
-Code

Comment: What do you mean by "It doesnt work"?

Comment: Have you tried doing a `var_dump($value)` right after your getattribute call? PHP functions will not know that they were called with a variable for an argument, versus being called via a hard-coded string. They just see the VALUE of whatever was in the function call.

Comment: Added in the warning message i got to the post above. Thanks for the help guys. -Code